# Install discourse with helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, discourse

I am currently installing Discourse with [helm charts](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/discourse). I run

```
kubectl create ns discourse
helm install my-release bitnami/discourse --namespace discourse
```

Sadly, when I run it, the deployment fails, saying for the `discourse` container in the `discourse` pod has the issue

```
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.4.41:8080/srv/status": dial tcp 192.168.4.41:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Did you check the pod logs?

Comment: This is what I get in the discourse container of the pod: `Failed to load logs: Get "https://10.1.0.19:10250/containerLogs/discourse/my-release-discourse-6b47f77db6-vnldj/discourse?tailLines=502&timestamps=true": dial tcp 10.1.0.19:10250: connect: connection refused
Reason: undefined (500)`

Comment: That's not your pod logs, that's an error saying it failed to get the pod logs. Looks like there is an issue with your cluster/kublet.

Comment: i am just able to run the same helm chart, it takes a bit to healthy and needs memory around 1GB. `helm install my-release bitnami/discourse --set image.debug=true `. also your cluster having issue or the kubectl which does not let you to tail logs.

Comment: @jordanm If it is a problem with the kubelet, how do I recognize it and how do I fix it?